# Use new fonts in MiKTeX

Tags: fonts

I'm using MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter and I'm trying to change the font for some parameters in mathematical formulas. Specifically, I would like to use capital letters of font "Libris". Is this possible? This font is listed in the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) and, according to the MiKTeX Package Manager, the package `libris` is installed. I don't know if this information is useful, but I haven't used LaTeX for much time until now.

Comment: Let's see if I understood your question correctly: You want all capital letters in mathematical formulas to be in Libris, and everything else to remain in the standard font?

Answer (score 1):

`\usepackage{libris}` should allow you to use this font.

Comment: Yes, "should" is the right word :) I've already tried in that way and even with the help of http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/fonts/libris/doc/fonts/libris/librisadf.pdf but with no success. When I try to write \textsf{...}, i get an error message: [DocOpen("%bm.pdf")][FileOpen("%bm.pdf")] Cannot execute the command. Even $\mathsf{...}$ doesn't work, as I get the usual sans serif font.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example so we can try and reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't mind using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can use any font that is installed in your system by means of package `fontspec`. Something on the following lines should do it

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{fontname}
```

As an additional benefit you gain the advantage of using OpenType font features.

Comment: Doesn’t works. Those directives are ignored and the resulting pdf is written using other fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `\renewcommand\sfdefault{yly}` ?

Comment: Thank you all, I managed to do what I was trying to do by defining the command `\newcommand\mt[1]{\fontfamily{yly}\selectfont\textit{\emph{#1}}}`. I didn't want to have a new default sans serif font: just to make the capital letters of `libris` available for some mathematical objects. The problem was just TeXniccenter: as I was advised to install TeXstudio instead, it solved by itself.
Thank you once more.